# Compiling latest UVC driver

Tags: uvc

I want to compile and use latest uvc driver on 12.04. I have researched on web but cannot find anything helpful.

Could you please give me some advices on this topic?

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux 2.6.26 and newer includes the Linux UVC driver natively. You will not need to download the driver sources manually unless you want to test a newer version or help with development.

To know how to download and compile please check [these official instructions](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#download)